# How to split table data into separately named Excel files with 'datepart' using an SSIS package?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis, business-intelligence

I followed this great link below to accomplish 90% of the work. But when I created excel files using 'dateparts' it only created the excel files, but did not load the data into those files.

[How to split table data into separate named Excel files using an SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520905/how-to-split-table-data-into-separate-named-excel-files-using-an-ssis-package)

Example: This link above showed how to create *North*, *South* and *Template* excel files from table values. But in my case I want to create **North_20130613**, **South_20130613** and  **template_20130613**. I created these files also, but was unable to load the data into them(extended with 'datepart').

I also would like to know how to append everyday data into those files.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I load the data into the file with the general name and then rename the file with the datapart afterwards.