# How to split table data into separate named Excel sheets in Excel File using an SSIS package?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

Hi I have same question with different Result Set .

[How to split table data into separate named Excel files using an SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520905/how-to-split-table-data-into-separate-named-excel-files-using-an-ssis-package)

Here in this question, SO expecting output into multiple Excel Files but here the same result Set need to be in multiple sheets in one excel file .

like 
Site = North related data in sheet1 and South related data in sheet2

Comment: Are the number of 'Site' groups fixed? If there are ten sites, you use ten data flow tasks. Each data flow has a source SQL statement limiting it to the site of interest and writes it to a particular excel file.

Comment: yes they are fixed @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Here's a guide: http://knowlton-group.com/using-ssis-to-export-data-to-excel follow that. Your first SQL query should be something like `select columns from table where site = 'North'`. Then repeat for each site. There are ways to do it in a loop but that's probably over the top. Post back with any questions.

Comment: but it will go into different excel files . North Data will go into one excel file South Data will go into one excel sheet . I want to both North and South Data in one excel file sheet 1 = North data and sheet 2 = South data  @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: According to that page you choose the destination file _then_ the excel sheet  So each data flow points at the same file, but a different sheet. Just make sure you data flows don't happen in parallel. Make sure there is a green workflow line between then to ensure that they run one after the other. Otherwise the file will be locked. PS I've never done this before - just following my nose.